# Using selenium to click on link not working despite correct xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I have the following setup

```
# Setup webdriver
wait = 10
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait)
```

I then navigate to a certain page - I have attached the inspect part below and want to click on the part highlighted in red

[image]

The code to implement this is below:

```
# Click on link
vs_table_path = "//a[@href='/care/chart/wandv/viewallclientvitals.jsp?ESOLstdvitalid=1&amp;ESOLview=Weights&amp;ESOLclientid=533354']"
vs_table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, vs_table_path)))
vs_table.click()
```

When I run this - it does not open up this link and I get a `TimeoutException` (from the `wait`).

I don't understand what the issue is here - I did the exact same thing on previous parts of the code to navigate the webpage and it worked. I also made sure the xpath matches exactly the attached inspect.

Please see href text below:

```
//a[@href='/care/chart/wandv/viewallclientvitals.jsp?ESOLstdvitalid=1&amp;ESOLview=Weights&amp;ESOLclientid=533354']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='view all']"))).click()
```

or

probably try this also :

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "view all"))).click()
```

Please refer [official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: I was just going to write exactly that :)

Comment: @C.Peck : I would still prefer `LINK_TEXT` :)

Comment: Interesting, I personally only use xpath and css selector (mostly all CSS Selectors), sometimes things don't work as I expect with `NAME`, `CLASS_NAME`, `LINK_TEXT`, etc

Comment: @C.Peck : with CSS you will not have much issues, cause their engines are same across almost every browser. Xpath does not  have consistency across different browser, now if they there are multiple linkText in a single page then we can't rely on linText for obvious reasons. I rarely use className, that's something I don't want to use.

Comment: @cruisepandey - thanks this works, but only issue is that I have multiple 'view all' on the webpage, hence why I used the href above. How can I differentiate between different 'view alls'?

Comment: @Ossz : That should work too, but it's difficult for me to write `href` from the screenshot, so always try to share in text format.

Comment: @cruisepandey Sorry, here's the href in full text copied:  //a[@href='/care/chart/wandv/viewallclientvitals.jsp?ESOLstdvitalid=1&amp;ESOLview=Weights&amp;ESOLclientid=533354']   Will add above also

Comment: I would suggest to use `//a[contains(@href, '/care/chart/wandv/viewallclientvitals.jsp?')]`  - Just check in the developer tool that there should not be multiple entry for this xpath

Comment: @cruisepandey - I've added it again - tbf it was already there I put it in the code snippet from before but also just shared the screenshot for reference purposes of HTML structure

Comment: @cruisepandey - I'm afraid the href implementation with 'contains' also doesn't work. It has to be through href as every 'view all' has a different href making the 'view all' click unique for that specific item that needs to be clicked

Comment: Every href will have unique URL right ? The one you are using that has lot of numbers, so if you are sure that href will never change then go ahead and use it. But make sure if in future it changes you would have change your xpath also

Comment: @cruisepandey - yes correct but I am still stuck on the same problem which is getting the click to work through href

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233338/discussion-between-cruisepandey-and-ossz).